# How can i use token for different level in log-in and test it in all function with laravel

Tags: laravel, api

i'm trying to make to different level for log-in in laravel project , so i'm asking about token , how can i use the token and test it in all my function

i created two table in data base , first one for client and second one for a resturant , and i have log-in for a resturant and client , so how can i make sure about if the token for a client or for a resturant anf how can i use it to make sure about auth in my functions

there is no code

log-in for a different level

Answer (score 0):

You can use token column name different  for cleint and resturant Or for evry login token is unique ever you can get token for current login users.